# Can we send an e-mail when protractor script fails, with email content as the error showing in the command prompt

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I am using protractor cucumber frame work.I have a requirement of sending email when the test failed.I am able to send email from AfterAll function,when the test failed.But i am not able to catch the error from command prompt in order to specify it as the content of the mail.How can i do this?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, how do you send email from protractor? A package I tried doesn't send anything because google prevents authorization

Comment: I am using @sendgrid/mail package to send an email.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to find a jasmine reporter that already exists that sends emails or build yourself a custom one. The reporter will need a `specDone()` function that will include details like failed expectations and stacktraces from the test that was just completed. Check out the [jasmine documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html#section-specDone) for more details.

Here is the example code snippet from the docs:

```
specDone: function(result) {
  console.log('Spec: ' + result.description + ' was ' + result.status);

  for(var i = 0; i < result.failedExpectations.length; i++) {
    console.log('Failure: ' + result.failedExpectations[i].message);
    console.log(result.failedExpectations[i].stack);
  }
}
```